# Difference between Activity and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-fragmentactivity

I was working on fragments and came across two things `Activity` and `FragmentActivity` which are used several times. I want to know that is there any difference between these two, because when I changed `Activity` with `FragmentActivity`, it had no effect on the app.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

A `FragmentActivity` is a subclass of `Activity` that was built for the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

The `FragmentActivity` class adds a couple new methods to ensure compatibility with older versions of Android, but other than that, there really isn't much of a difference between the two. Just make sure you change all calls to `getLoaderManager()` and `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportLoaderManager()` and `getSupportFragmentManager()` respectively.

Comment: Hey I didn't change the calls to getSupportLoaderManager() and getSupportFragmentManager()..but still it is working fine.

Comment: That's what makes it so dangerous :P. `FragmentActivity` inherits the `getLoaderManager` and `getFragmentManager` methods from `Activity` and as a result the compiler won't complain. Chances are you are importing the incorrect `LoaderManager` and `FragmentManager` classes too. Make sure you are importing these classes from the support package (`android.support.v4.app`), *not* the Android SDK (`android.app`).

Comment: Can we say that if we want to use fragments for android 2.x version we need to use FragmentActivity nad for version that support fragments we need to use Activity .

Comment: I think what you are saying is correct. But just to be 100% clear...  use `Activity` if you are using `android.app.Fragment`; use `FragmentActivity` if you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Never attach a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to a `android.app.Activity`, as this will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Can you suggest where could i find a good tutorial for fragments.

Comment: First try [**this tutorial**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) (how to use `Fragments` in an application). Then, continue on to [**this tutorial**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/) (how to make use of the `Fragment`s from the support package). The [**documentation**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) on the developers site is worth reading as well.

Comment: @AlexLockwood I am importing the correct classes i.e. `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` and `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, but still getting the error at `getFragmentManager()`. Why doesn't it inherit `getFragmentManager()` from the `Activity` because `FragmentActivity` extends `Activity`

Comment: Maybe it is not a compilation error and it is just a lint analysis error. Either way, you should be using `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your `FragmentActivity` instead.

Answer (score 8):

`FragmentActivity` is part of the [support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html), while `Activity` is the framework's default class. They are functionally equivalent.

You should always use `FragmentActivity` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of the platform default `Activity` and `android.app.Fragment` classes. Using the platform defaults mean that you are relying on whatever implementation of fragments is used in the device you are running on. These are often multiple years old, and contain bugs that have since been fixed in the support library.

Comment: Note: `minSdkVersion` of support library is 14 since version 26.x.x.