# Actionbar tabs with multi-pane view in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am newbie with fragments and actionbar in android.
I want to develop application for tablets which has multiple tabs, each tab has Listview in the leftside and the details of the item on the right side

[Here](http://c1345842.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/assets/cdn_files/assets/000/002/355/original.png?1306257738) is an example of what i want to do.

I don't know which of this is activity and which is a fragment and how to navigate using this tabs and change the content of the listview and the details.

I want examples to navigate using tabs with multipane layout because I searched about that and I found tabs are using fragments and multipane is composed of two fragments and nested fragments not allowed in android.

And I want to know: What is the difference between activity and fragmentActivity?

Comment: Did you get the solution? Pls I also wanted to do like this. Still couldn't

Comment: No , i didn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

**Fragment Tutorials**

Google "android fragment tutorial" and you'll get a lot of results like this:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Don't stick with only one though because many of them vary just slightly and if you do two or three then you'll have a better understanding of how fragments work (standalone or multipane).

**Fragments with Tabs**

A great way to see an example of switching fragments is by creating a new android project in Eclipse using the latest ADT. Create a new Android Application Project and when you're setting the name of the main activity you have an option to set the navigation type. Choose tabs or tabs+swipe. This will generate a clean project for you to see the very basics of how to switch fragments using tabs.

**Activity vs FragmentActivity**
Essentially, an  `Activity` may contain a layout with no fragments and a `FragmentActivity` may contain a layout with fragments. This answer has a few more details: [Difference between Activity and FragmentActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity)

Comment: vogella tutorials is awesome , i tried it and it works prefectly, but when i tried to add actionbar with multipane i have some troubles with oriantation , i thought there is another way to replace fargments in case of using action bar tabs or i still missing somthing to understand