# What's the core difference between fragment and activity? Which code can be written in fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, fragment

I have three tabs with three fragments each and one main activity, and i want to create the socket to send the message over wifi network, so where should i write the code for it? In that particular fragment class or main activity?

Comment: check this links this may helps you..[fragments vs activitys][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views

Comment: A Fragment is not completely stand-a-lone, it needs an activity as a host. While an activity can be instantiated on it's own. I see that as the major difference.

Comment: [This is an another link, and it answers your question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity

Comment: thanks alot, can you help me about my described scenario?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course you can write any code inside the fragment but you need to take care of a few things. While accessing anything that requires a context or something that is specific to an activity you will need to get a reference to the super activity of the fragment, e.g. while creating an intent inside an activity you do something like this :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SomeActivity.class);
```

but inside a fragment you will have to do something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(super.getActivity(),SomeActivity.class);
```

Similarly if you are accessing some thing from the layout file of the fragment. You need to perform the following steps:

1)get a global reference to the parent layout of your fragment inside your fragment. e.g

```
    private LinearLayout result_view;
```

2) Implement the OnCreateView method instead of onCreate method.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return result_view;
    }
```

3) Inflate the fragment layout like this inside the onCreateView method of the fragment:

```
    result_view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.image_detail_pager, container, false);
```

4) you can now access layout views like this :

```
    layout_a = (LinearLayout) result_view
            .findViewById(R.id.some_layout_id);
```

Comment: actually i want to create socket in order to broadcast the message over LAN but now the button on which i will listen for the broadcast event is in one of the fragment,then can i write the broadcasting message code inside fragment?