# What is the best way to move on NavigationDrawer pattern?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I provide NavigationDrawer in my app.

I'am using manual on http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

```
/**
 * Swaps fragments in the main content view
 */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
    // position
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Here I must put my screen like Fragment, but now my screen is Activity, and I want to move from my Activity to Fragment with minimal code change. What can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution it's just change extending from Activity to Fragment, change onCreate() to onActivityCreated() and move layout.xml linking on onCreateView()

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity/)
you should be able to convert your activity to a fragmentactivity and Then use the navigation drawer. Also see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for sample app

Comment: You don't undarstand question. It's not a problem to convert MainActivity from Activity to FragmentActivity or ActionBarActivity. Problem in rewritting NotMainActivity (what will be populated in NavigationDrawer) in Fragment.