# Google Maps v2 not loading

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

google maps does not load and gives a blank screen
tried a few guides and tried google's guide but none seem to work
this is all i have added, couldnt find a problem :-/

logcat:

```
06-27 01:21:16.470: I/Google Maps Android API(12628): Google Play services client version: 4452000
06-27 01:21:16.490: I/Google Maps Android API(12628): Google Play services package version: 4452036
06-27 01:21:16.790: D/dalvikvm(12628): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3003K, 16% free 17823K/21008K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
06-27 01:21:16.800: I/fpp(12628): Making Creator dynamically
06-27 01:21:16.800: I/Google Maps Android API(12628): Google Play services client version: 4452000
06-27 01:21:16.810: W/ActivityThread(12628): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
06-27 01:21:17.261: I/Google Maps Android API(12628): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
06-27 01:21:24.709: D/dalvikvm(12628): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3259K, 15% free 19643K/23084K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
06-27 01:21:32.367: E/Google Maps Android API(12628): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    android:versionCode="1"
    package="com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />    

    <permission
            android:name="com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
             android:value="AIzaSyDTkYW-kWs9VKB40pv7Qhw972blaz-GD1A" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".activities.MyActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        

        <activity
            android:name="com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.InfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".activities.MyActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>              

        <activity
            android:name="com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.IqamahActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".activities.MyActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>          

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity :

```
package com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity;

import com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class IqamahActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iqamah);
    }
}
```

layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/iqamah_map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: What’s the value of @integer/google_play_services_version??

Comment: thnx, sorry i fell asleep XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Your Code** .I hope it helps you . It working for me !

```
package com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity;

import com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class IqamahActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iqamah);
map =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.iqamah_map)).getMap();

    }
}
```

Change your **XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/iqamah_map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

For,More information Please Visit [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map)

Comment: @SimplePlan Sir : I have faced same problem . Then use it .Actually SupportMapFragment belongs to the v4 support library, contrary to the default MagFragment that is a native component in Android.

Comment: @A Ya that's reason. but another reason is if your `minsdk<12` then you should used `SupportMapFrgament` for Backward compability Support and your activity should also extends `FragmentActivity` for that.

Comment: @SimplePlan Yes yes .Glad to receive your information .

Answer (score 1):

Amiya is right, you need to use [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) to use Fragments.

To find out the difference between Activity and FragmentActivity, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity) might help!

if you're targeting API 12 and above, you can use MapFragment. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Click [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map) to view more about Google Maps Android API v2.

Hope this helps!