# Insert Buttons and Menus (slide menu) in a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `FragmentActivity` which has a SupportMapFragment. I want to add buttons, menus (slide menu)...how could I do this?

here is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private LocalizeDB db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    db = new LocalizeDB(this);
}



 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


 private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) is a subclass of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Most of all things you do with an Activity you can do with a `FragmentActivity` (some differences are stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477997/difference-between-activity-and-fragmentactivity)).

I think you will use your `activity_maps` layout to place additional buttons. The slide menu may be implemented as a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). Let me know if I've missed something.

Hope it helps!