# FlutterActivity vs FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I was trying to implement `local_auth` package into my Flutter app.

in the documentation, it was mentioned that it will have to use `FlutterFragmentActivity` instead of `FlutterActivity` in my MainActivity class.

So I wanted to know what are the main differences between `FlutterFragmentActivity` and `FlutterActivity` and how both impact app's `performance`?

:) as I don't want to make a change and break the app in production.

Comment: FlutterFragmentActivity exists because there are some Android APIs in the ecosystem that only accept a FragmentActivity. If a FragmentActivity is not required, you should consider using a regular FlutterActivity instead, because FlutterActivity is considered to be the standard, canonical implementation of a Flutter Activity.

Answer (score 5):

A FragmentActivity is a subclass of Activity that was built for the Android Support Package.

The FragmentActivity class adds a couple of new methods to ensure compatibility with older versions of Android, but other than that, there really isn't much of a difference between the two.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library

Info from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/10478048/7198006

So, it doesn't impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps, I see those activities act differently when you press back button (or perform back gesture) at the root screen of your app:

`FlutterActivity`: Your app will **be closed**.

`FlutterFragmentActivity` : Your app will **be move to background**.